# Css html. Как сделать круглый пунктирный див как шкала. Пример на картинке

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

Помогите плиз.

Как сделать эту желтую шкалу?

[image: Изображение]

Answer (score 3):

как-то так

```css
#rds{
  border: 5px dashed;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  border-radius: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rds"></div>
```

Comment: Неа, мне жаль но я так тоже делал.

Comment: что нет? чем не подходит?)))) вопрос был - как сделать круглый пунктирный див, я думаю что ответ соответствует! )

Comment: Нет. я же дал картинку.
Если б все так просто - вопрос не ставил б.

Comment: друг мой, как вопрос поставлен, такой и ответ! а решать чужие задачи целиком тут никто не будет, для этого есть фриланс.ру

Comment: @SirGrey Если вы "так уже делали" - надо приводить СВОЙ код ПРИ написании вопроса и сразу указывать что именно не получается делать. Текущий вопрос действительно сформулирован так невнятно, что ответ  вполне себе подходит - тут отвечающий вполне прав.

Comment: совет, не можешь сделать так, сделай картинкой ;) или вектором если умеешь!

Comment: Если вам требуется, чтобы пунктирная линия была обрезана, то это можно реализовать, создав пунктирный круг и наложив на него отдельные невидимые блоки, которые будут обрезать часть круга: https://jsfiddle.net/ostapenko25/1ysqLoh3/   Аналогично делаете второй круг, с серыми делениями, и вырезаете из него нужную часть. Затем совмещаете два круга, наложив один на другой так, чтобы они сложились в нужную картину. Но вообще это действительно проще и оптимальнее сделать в SVG.